# Different elements on this page appear to scroll at different speeds. How was this done?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, pagespeed

The effect i am refering to is visible at http://whyinteractive.com/showreel. The elements appear to scroll behind and in front of one another at different speeds creating some cool effects. How was this done?

Comment: Another great example is the github 404: http://github.com/404

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What you are looking for is called the Parallax effect.

You can learn more at sites like:

http://locomotivation.squeejee.com/post/109269802/jquery-parallax-scrolling-build-your-own-1980s-video-gam

http://stephenmcintyre.net/blog/jquery-parallax-scrolling/

**UPDATE**:

This is pretty much exactly what you need:

CODE: [Build a parallax scrolling website interface with jQuery & CSS](http://f6design.com/journal/2011/08/06/build-a-parallax-scrolling-website-interface-with-jquery-and-css/)

DEMO: [Parallax Scrolling](http://f6design.com/projects/parallax-scrolling/)